# Manipulating aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose these are my aggregation results

```
"buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "weightInKg",
                    "doc_count": 500
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "numberOfPeople",
                    "doc_count": 25
                 }
              ]
```

Here I want to get the ratio "weightInKg/numberOfPeople". Is it possible to get such results in the response itself in elasticsearch?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: You will need to use pipeline aggregations for this